# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application with spring tool suite. I get following error when running as 'Spring boot app'

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: public com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.TaskServiceInterface com.frameworkonly.webapp.controller.HomeController.taskServiceInterface; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.TaskServiceInterface] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.frameworkonly.webapp.SpringBootDemoApplication.main(SpringBootDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: public com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.TaskServiceInterface com.frameworkonly.webapp.controller.HomeController.taskServiceInterface; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.TaskServiceInterface] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.frameworkonly.webapp.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.frameworkonly.webapp.domain.Task;
import com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.TaskServiceInterface;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    public TaskServiceInterface taskServiceInterface;

 @RequestMapping("/home")
 public String home(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("allTasks", (ArrayList<Task>)taskServiceInterface.getAllTasks());
     System.out.print("calling tasks");
  return "tasks";
 }
}
```

**TaskServiceInterface**

```
package com.frameworkonly.webapp.service;

import java.util.Collection;

import com.frameworkonly.webapp.domain.Task;

public interface TaskServiceInterface {

    public Task saveTask(Task task);

    public Boolean deleteTask(Long taskId);

    public Task editTask(Task task);

    public Task findTask(Long taskId);

    public Collection<Task> getAllTasks();
}
```

**TaskServiceImplementation**

```
package com.frameworkonly.webapp.service;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.frameworkonly.webapp.domain.Task;
import com.frameworkonly.webapp.repository.TaskRepository;

public class TaskServiceImplementation implements TaskServiceInterface{

    @Autowired
    protected TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Override
    public Task saveTask(Task task) {
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean deleteTask(Long taskId) {
        Task temp = taskRepository.findOne(taskId);
        if(temp!=null){
             taskRepository.delete(temp);
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Task editTask(Task task) {
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @Override
    public Task findTask(Long taskId) {
        return taskRepository.findOne(taskId);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Task> getAllTasks() {
        Iterable<Task> itr = taskRepository.findAll();
        return (Collection<Task>)itr;
    }

}
```

**SpringBootDemoApplication**

```
package com.frameworkonly.webapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

it runs fine when I remove `@Autowired` annotation from `HomeController` but get `NullPointerException` when launching the app as `localhost:8080/home`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.frameworkonly.webapp.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
```

Comment: Add your `SpringBootDemoApplication` and also in what package is the actual implementation of the `TaskServiceInterface`?

Comment: post updated with these classes.

Comment: Put `@Service` on `TaskServiceImplementation `. Without it it won't be picked up.

Comment: it worked. thanks mate. can you add it as an answer so I could acknowledge that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an annotation on your implementation. It should be annotated with `@Service` or another `@Component` annotation for spring to pick it up using component-scanning.